# NDK64 and NDK32 r10

Tags: android, android-ndk

I just saw the 10th release of the [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) and I don't understand exactly the new split of the packages for each platforms (Windows or Linux for 32 and 64 bit versions, for every one of these there are two packages now). Since three new platforms have been added (arm64-v8a, x86_64 and mips64), ndk32 packages are required to target 32 bit versions of Android and ndk64 target the new 64 bit versions? I hope someone will help me understand this new division between the packages, thanks.

Comment: I've understood the new _android-ndk64-r10_ packages support compiling for both 32 and 64 bit targets. But since _Android L_ is the first/only 64 bit supporting platform it's been put into separate package (at least for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is definitively resolved since with the latest two releases they offer unified packages for every platforms.

Answer (score 5):

I was confused also.

I interpreted it as harsim said, that is:
(32-bit target) indicates the target android device is 32-bit.
(64-bit target) indicates the target android device is 64-bit.

Comment: I guess if you use 64 bit version you target 32bit as well, no?

Comment: I would expect no. 32-bit and 64-bit are different targets. Sometimes vendors provide backwards support, or maybe the build system has changed since then.

Comment: What is 64 bit device? Can you name some? Is Samsung s5 64?if not i am using 64 ndk and it works on it